# Save item from UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, plist, nsuserdefaults

I am creating a TableView based application. The tableView is loading in the external last 12 items of the XML feed. It all works perfect.

So now I want to create an extra "save favorite item function". There are 2 ways to achieve this:

**1. Custom AccessoryButton**

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

**2. (customized) edit tableview**

```
if ([self.tableView isEditing])
```

My question is: which option do you prefer and can you give an example of how to achieve this?

Any serious answer will be appreciated.

Thank you for your answer. Thanks to Matt I've fixed it with the following code:

```
        NSMutableDictionary *item = [dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    BOOL checked = [[item objectForKey:@"checked"] boolValue];
    //cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    //cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    UIImage *image = (checked) ? [UIImage   imageNamed:@"first.png"] : [UIImage imageNamed:@"second.png"];
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, image.size.width, image.size.height);
    button.frame = frame;
    [button setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(checkButtonTapped:event:)  forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    button.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    cell.accessoryView = button;
```

As you can see Im using a dataAray now. Im also using a plist which stores the "checked boolian". This does not work properly, because:

1. Checkmarks aren't placed correct (according to the plist)
2. When UitableView scrollview moves the checkmarks change radomly.

SO I want to create an array which stores Id's of the selected items. Then iterate through the array to see if an ID is present in the array. If yes: Star if No: graystar.

Do you think this is a good solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I very much prefer accessory button approach. Since editing mode is typically used to remove or re-oder items, the user would not usually look there or expect it to perform any other functions.

Having said that, I would not recommend using the accessory button without changing its default image. Since the default image of the accessory button usually means displaying more details about the current item, it might cause confusion if not changed to a more descriptive image. Also,  optimally the image should be different if the current item is marked as a favorite (e.g. a grey star if it's not a favorite, and a golden star if it is). The code should be really straight forward:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

  cell = UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Identifier"];
  if(!cell)
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"Identifier"]

  UIImage *accessoryImage;
  ItemClass *item = [self.items objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
  // you might want to cache the images instead of creating them for each cell
  if(item.favorite)
    accessoryImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"goldenStar.png"];  
  else
    accessoryImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"greyStar.png"];  
  cell.accessoryView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:accessoryImage];
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  ItemClass *item = [self.items objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
  item.favorite = !item.favorite;

  // update the cell with the new image and any other data you need modified
  [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
}
```

Good luck!

Comment: WHat do you exactly mean with: itemClass?

Comment: That's whatever class you've created for your items.